# Cannot connect to an Instance using ssh after Broken pipe

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, provisioning, salt-stack

I'm totally new using SaltStack and AWS, probably this is a dumb question, I created an AMI (using packer) with SaltStack (masterless) as a provisioner... I was able to connect via ssh and make a configuration to the minion. I was able to run `salt-call state.highstate` successfully.
Later, I lost the connection to my instance, 
(`[root@<ip> ec2-user]# Write failed: Broken pipe`) and after that, I wasn't able to connect again.

*What's been tried:*

1. Reboot the instance and didn't work
2. I've checked the permissions on the .ssh files and they seem fine
3. Create a new instance and use the same key.pem and I was able to connect to this new instance.

I'm not sure if I'm missing a configuration in SaltStack. Is there a possibility that the keys on my instance changed after running `salt-call state.highstate` ??

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing inherent in running highstate that would have terminated the SSH connection and prevented you from reconnecting. I would suspect it's something in your SLS files which is breaking SSH - which is applied when you run highstate.

Things that might have been done by your Salt states:

- your SSH keys were removed/mangled
- `opensshd` config was changed
- `openssh-server` was uninstalled

EDIT: Having seen the output from Salt in the pastebin linked in comments, it's probably the `AuthorizedKeysFile` option being commented out:

```
-AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
+#AuthorizedKeysFile    .ssh/authorized_keys
```

I recommend using [file.replace](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.replace) to patch in specific changes you need, as opposed to replacing the whole `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with a new version.

Comment: Thank you, seems the keys were changed, but I didn't change the ssh config. :(

Comment: Try running the process again and make sure you keep an eye on the output from salt. If you can drop it in a pastebin (which SSH keys removed!) then I can have a look